# Regex for alphanumeric (unicode) with specific length

Tags: .net, asp.net, regex

Valid ones should contain at least one number or letter (from 6 to 15 chars long) in any order. e.x.

```
11111a

111a11

a11111
```

I found similar posts within SO but they seem to be out of order...

Comment: I find the specification rather unclear. Should the entire string be 6-15 characters long, or should there be a sequence of 6-15 letters in the string. Are any non-letter and non-number characters allowed in the string?

Comment: the entire string should be from 6 to 15 characters long and any non-letter or non-number should not be allowed.
Sorry about that, my native language is Greek...

Comment: @strakastroukas - I appreciate that English isn't your first language, however could you add a few more test cases for us - including ones that shouldn't be accepted - according to the comments we have "111111" is not valid, but "ελληνικά" is - is the "ά" your number?

Comment: @Zhaph - "ελληνικά1" does not validate too. The first one was a typo. Sorry about that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will match 6 to 15 characters (letters or digits), except all digits or all letters:

```
^(\p{L}|\p{N}){6,15}(?<=\p{L}.*)(?<=\p{N}.*)$
```

aaaaa1aaaa **matches**

1111111a11 **matches**

aaaaaaaaaa **doesn't match**

1111111111 **doesn't match**

Comment: Looks like this could be the one: http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=a49ea7cd-964f-4127-b5f6-b4c3a7d76515

Comment: I agree.  This looks better than mine.  I was just reading up about the \p notation here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html

It looks like this is the trick to making this work.

Answer (score 0):

You would need a look ahead query for that one.

You can create a regexp token that will try to find a match, but will not "*consume*" the input string. You can follow that one with a simple 2nd query that will validate the length of your string.

You can combine those to create the query you desire.

The syntax for the .Net Version of the RegEx engine would be something like this:

This RegEx is only written in this chatbox, and not tested... so have mercy :)

I am not sure whats a "Character or letter, but I will assume you mean "a-Z"

```
(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{6,15}
```

Comment: a-zA-Z will only match the roman letters a through z. It will not match any characters like å or ö - For more info, see "The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)": http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: ooups! sorry about that..  i mean number or letter

Comment: You could use \w (lower cased) instead of a-zA-Z.  This would also match unicode word characters.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx#WordCharacter

Comment: @yodaj007: note that `\w` also matches underscore characters.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this works:

```
^(?=.*[a-zA-Z].*)\w{6,15}(?<=.*\d.*)$
```

And here it is with test cases:

http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=83761a1e-f6ae-4660-a91f-9cdc4d69c7b3

Basically my idea was to use a positive lookahead first to ensure at least one letter is included.  Then I use \w{5,16} as a simple means of ensuring that I match the correct number of characters (and that they are alphanumeric).  And then at the end I use a positive lookbehind to ensure that the string includes at least one number as well.

Comment: Yep, nice one, well done - it also works with unicode, which doesn't appear in your test cases: http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=1f06c36f-41dd-4526-9c23-db1b1677ad1b

Comment: Well, it's looking explicitly for unicode letters and Arabic numerals in the 0-9 range - which ones are the numerals in your string there?

Comment: @strakastroukas -- Interesting, I'm not sure how to match that off the top of my head.

Comment: @Zhaph
@TheSteve

Edited: this should not fail in validation but it does "Ελληνικά1"

Answer (score -1):

That should do it: `\w{6,15}`
if you want to match the whole string: `^\w{6,15}$`

Comment: This doesn't match the requirement *should contain at least one character or letter*

Comment: thats true.. 111111 is not valid